# Why does including an error type in a python except block reduce runtime?

Tags: python, runtime, valueerror

I was looking at solutions for LeetCode problem 8 (string to integer) and there is one with that uses try: except: blocks and when using this solution, removing the type of error from the except heading drastically increased runtime. Why is this?

```
try:
     n = int(n)
except ValueError as ex: ## runtime 24 ms
     return 0
```

versus

```
try:
     n = int(n)
except: ## runtime 28 ms
     return 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure 4 ms would count as drastically increasing runtime ;) Just out of curiosity, what are you using to measure runtime?

Comment: @JeffB Thanks for the prompt reply. It doesn't drastically increase the magnitude of the runtime but LeetCode "grades" each submission relative to the others so the 4 ms difference drops me from the 75th percentile in submission speed to around the 35th. Sorry for the inaccurate wording. Each submission uses a particular set of test cases and I think this measurement is the average. When submitting individual test cases they seem to be near this time. I can post the full code and an example test case if that would help.